# Comutative inverse operation question

Tags: arithmetic

From pre algebra for Dummies

Comutative

> > When the second number is missing in a subtraction or multiplication problem, just switch
> > around the two values that are next to the equal sign (that is, the blank and the equal sign:

I can’t understand that: just switch around the two values that are next to the equal sign (that is, the blank and the equal sign:

15-.......=8 ——>15-8=.......

The blank and the equal sign ?
Explain me more

Comment: *commutative* has two *m*'s

Comment: I don't understand what there is to not understand.  From $a-b=c$ you can add $b$ to both sides to get $a-b+b=c+b$.  Now, use that $-b+b=0$ to get $a+0=c+b$ and omit the zero to get $a=c+b$.  Now, subtract $c$ from both sides to get $a-c = c+b-c$.  Rearrange the right side a bit and use that $c-c=0$ to get that $a-c=b+(c-c)$ simplifying to $a-c=b+0$ and omitting the zero to get $a-c=b$.  These all follow from rudimentary properties of addition, subtraction, and zero

Comment: All they are saying is that $a-b = c\implies a-c=b$.  As an example... $15-7=8$ and $15-8=7$

Comment: What does it mean by saying to switch the blank and equal sing

Comment: `15` `-` `x` `=` `8` can become `15` `-` `8` `=` `x`.  We are swapping the value to the left of the equals sign (*the `x`*) with the value to the right of the equals sign (*the `8`*).  We are not swapping the equals sign with anything.